# getCurrentPosition in JS does not work on iOS

Tags: javascript, ios, macos, google-chrome, safari

I have a page that contains a code that gets the current location from the device and load other stuff based on the location with this code:

```
if (navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(successFunction);
} else {
    // Make API call to the GeoIP services
}
```

It works on all android devices that I tested, but on iOS and macOS, it’s not working. Neither `if` nor `else`. Seems like it stuck at getting the current location.

Any help?

Comment: Display error and you will know what is happening -> [look](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Geolocation/getCurrentPosition#Example)
`navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(success, error, options);`

Comment: @The Rock, does your website served via https?

Comment: No it is primarily on `localhost` and the staging server is not supporting `https`. I tested on the production server and it worked as it is.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

iOS and macOS doesn't give you the user's location if they don't allow it  **or** if the system can not trust you. So:

### - First (Probably your answer)

It works with the exact code you provided **ONLY IF** the host (aka the origin) is using **https**. That is the cause of permission alert not showing up due to your comment to an answer below.

Remember if you not use **https**, it will be stuck for about a minute and then returns an error about authentication failure. Use **error** to check that:

```
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(success, error, options)
```

It will tell you something like this:

> [blocked] Access to geolocation was blocked over insecure connection
>   to http://example.com.

**Tip:** You can refresh the page after you requested the location to skip the waiting process. But don't forget to check the *Preserve Log* option in the inspector.

### - Second:

If you are using **https**, then check your location settings for Safari, which might have  been set to OFF somehow, you can change it here: Settings > Privacy > Location Services > Safari. This is not the default option, but maybe you changed it accidentally. So don't worry about the users if this was the issue. And if you use Chrome or any other third party browsers, head to its settings and check for location access. It's not there by default and appears only if location wanted at least once.

### - Third:

If you are about to load your web **inside an app** using `webView`, make sure to add *location permission descriptions* to the **info.plist** file. Add `NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription` versus `NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription` versus `NSLocationUsageDescription` as your needs.

For the sake of completeness, on iOS13, you can not get `always` permission. But this is not the point here and the point is you have to get the required permissions sometime **before** you need to get the location from GPS or it is not going to work at all.

Comment: You are right! It was because of the `https` and the **tip** helped me to fetch the error message. But how can I test that on my machine? Localhost is not `https`.

Comment: It is a different question. You can search it [here](https://www.google.com/search?client=safari&rls=en&q=localhost+https&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8)

Comment: The "Second" section above worked for me. Make sure not only Location Services in general is enabled. But also make sure it is enabled specifically for Safari (as mentioned above). Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

**You need to check three things**

Here's what you need to check to understand why your procedure does not have access to the user's location. Your code should ensure these three things:

1. The user's **Operating System** has location services enabled.
2. The user's **browser** supports checking for location services.
3. The user's browser has location services **enabled**.

Combining the answers on the page and one additional check, we can handle all three of these scenarios:

```
    /* Set up getCurrentPosition options with a timeout */
    const navigatorLocationOptions = {
      enableHighAccuracy: true,
      timeout: 5000,
      maximumAge: 0
    };

    /* Determine browser permissions status */
    navigator.permissions.query({name:'geolocation'})
      .then((result) => {
        /* result.state will be 'granted', 'denied', or 'error' */
        if (result.state === 'granted') {
          navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(pos => {
             console.log('Retrieved user location', pos);
             /* Got the location! Write your successful code here. */            

          }, (error) => {
            /* System/OS location services disabled */
            console.log('System/OS services disabled', navigator);
            noLocationFound();
          }, navigatorLocationOptions);

        } else {
          /* Browser location services disabled or error */
          console.log('Browser location services disabled', navigator);
          noLocationFound();
        }
      }, (error) => {
        /* Browser doesn't support querying for permissions */
        console.log('Browser permissions services unavailable', navigator);
        noLocationFound()
      }
    );
    
    /* Handle no location found */
    function noLocationFound() {
      /* Write code here to handle: user location is unavailable */
    }
```

Simply add your handling code for user notification and fallback in the `noLocationFound()` function.

Answer (score 2):

GeoLocation works only if a user provides his/her permissions.

Make sure that is the case.

[This CodePen demo](https://codepen.io/jasonrammoray/pen/KONgZQ) has been tested in iOS simulator with Safari and successfully shown the latitude and the longitude.

[image]

```js
var options = {
  enableHighAccuracy: true,
  timeout: 5000,
  maximumAge: 0
};

function log(data) {
  const tag = document.createElement('p');
  tag.textContent = data;
  document.body.appendChild(tag);
}

function success(pos) {
  var crd = pos.coords;
  console.log('Successfully determined a user position:', crd);

  log('Your current position is:');
  log(`Latitude : ${crd.latitude}`);
  log(`Longitude: ${crd.longitude}`);
  log(`More or less ${crd.accuracy} meters.`);
}

function error(err) {
  console.warn(`ERROR(${err.code}): ${err.message}`);
}

navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(success, error, options);
```

It can't be the case if your code doesn't hit either `if` nor `else` unless some other code has triggered an infinite loop earlier in your code.

Comment: Make sure the permission will be prompted to a user: https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/142065?hl=en&co=GENIE.Platform%3DiOS&oco=1

Comment: The code snippet you provided is not working on macOS safari likely because of the exact same issue of the original question. Showing this: *ERROR(2): Origin does not have permission to use Geolocation service*

Comment: Very likely.
In my case a user is given a prompt:
'The website "s.codepen.io" would like to use your current location'.
Selecting 'Allow' shows the current coordinates.
Double-check if you have "Enable Location Services" checkbox ticked in Settings -> Security & Privacy -> Location Services.
Don't forget to tick the respective checkbox next to Safari in the list of the apps that have permission to determine your location.

Comment: Thanks for your time and effort, I used your code already and as I said, the permission not came up. Even in this code snippet. My issue was about `https` that @MojtabaHosseini mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

I just encountered the same issue. The simple answer is to ask the user, to give the permission to your browser in

```
Settings > Privacy > Location Services.
```