# getCurrentLocation() doesn't work on mobile browser (iOS Safari / Brave)

Tags: javascript, html

I have a problem where I want to get the user's current location and display it, by using the following code:

```
var x = document.getElementById("test01");

function getLocation() {
  if (navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);
  } else {
    x.innerHTML = "Geolocation is not supported by this browser.";
  }
}

function showPosition(position) {
  x.innerHTML = "Latitude: " + position.coords.latitude +
  "<br>Longitude: " + position.coords.longitude;
}
```

It works no problem on my desktop and laptop computers, in Safari, Brave, and Chrome, I only had to accept ther permisions in each browser.

Is there a reason that this may not work on a mobile device? Do I have to make a special request of some sort? Or is it simply not possible?

I would like to keep the code in vanilla JS if possible, and avoid any frameworks.

Comment: Try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57130901/getcurrentposition-in-js-does-not-work-on-ios

Comment: Your code works fine on iPadIOS 14 Safari - I was asked for permission similar to how I was asked on Windows10 Edge browser. According to [link]https://caniuse.com/?search=getcurrentposition you should be OK on all the common browsers.

Comment: I was running my web app on a test server with XAMMP, it seams that that was the problem, as soon as I put it on my hosing site, it worked like a charm.