# geolocation.getCurrentPosition on Safari on iOS

Tags: ios, geolocation, mobile-safari

I'm using the code below (taken from [w3schools.com](https://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_geolocation_error)) and **only on Safari + iOS** it delivers the error "permission_denied".

I'm using https, the permission for Safari to access the position on my page is set to "allow" and I'm not using webView (as described in this [almost identical question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57130901/getcurrentposition-in-js-does-not-work-on-ios)).

It works flawless on Safari with iPadOS or macOS, also on Firefox on iOS.

What's so special about Safari on iOS and how can this be solved?

```
function getLocation() {
  if (navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition, showError);
  } else { 
    x.innerHTML = "Geolocation is not supported by this browser.";
  }
}

function showPosition(position) {
  x.innerHTML = "Latitude: " + position.coords.latitude + 
  "<br>Longitude: " + position.coords.longitude;
}

function showError(error) {
  switch(error.code) {
    case error.PERMISSION_DENIED:
      x.innerHTML = "User denied the request for Geolocation."
      break;
    case error.POSITION_UNAVAILABLE:
      x.innerHTML = "Location information is unavailable."
      break;
    case error.TIMEOUT:
      x.innerHTML = "The request to get user location timed out."
      break;
    case error.UNKNOWN_ERROR:
      x.innerHTML = "An unknown error occurred."
      break;
  }
}
```

Comment: Solved it on my own: There are **two** places to turn on location services:
1. Go to Settings > Privacy > Location Services
2. While using Safari > open View menu > tap aA > website settings

Comment: thanks berroniko for posting your solution 

Answer (score -1):

In the web do below / or use navigator with a popup dialog

```
 var options = {
  enableHighAccuracy: true,
  timeout: 7000,
  maximumAge: 0
};

function log(data) {
  const tag = document.createElement('p');
  tag.textContent = data;
  document.body.appendChild(tag);
}

function success(pos) {
  var crd = pos.coords;
  console.log('Successfully determined a user position:', crd);

  log('Your current position is:');
  log(`Latitude : ${crd.latitude}`);
  log(`Longitude: ${crd.longitude}`);
  log(`More or less ${crd.accuracy} meters.`);
}

function error(err) {
  console.warn(`ERROR(${err.code}): ${err.message}`);
}

navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(success, error, options);
```

Or

```
$scope.watchId = navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(function (position) {
                        if ($scope.t1 == 0) {
                            $scope.t1 = position.timestamp;
                        } else {
                            if (Math.abs($scope.t1 - position.timestamp) > 5000) {
                                $scope.t1 = position.timestamp;
                                SellerRef.update({ Location: { Lat: position.coords.latitude, Long: position.coords.longitude } })
                            }
                        }
    
                    },
                        function (error) {
                            if (error.code == 1) {
                                  $scope.showAlert("An error occured \n" + " Please goto Settings->Privacy->LocationServices and give permission for " + bowser.name + " which is your browser ");
                            }
    
                        }
                    );
```

---

For loading your web **inside an app**

- Then with `webView`, just add *location permission descriptions* to the **info.plist** file.
- Add `NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription` versus `NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription` versus `NSLocationUsageDescription`

> What is the geolocation error, look [here](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2016/04/geolocation-on-secure-contexts-only#can_i_detect_at_runtime_if_the_geolocation_was_blocked_because_of_not_being_on_a_secure_context)

```
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(success => {
  /* Do some magic. */
}, failure => {
  if (failure.message.startsWith("Only secure origins are allowed")) {
    // Secure Origin issue.
  }
});
```

Include/set an "required_features" option at manifest.webapp file:

```
{
  "required_features": ["geolocation"]
}
```

User:

On iPhone:

```
Settings -> Location Services -> [your Browser] [apple ref][1]
```

[Chrome](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2016/04/geolocation-on-secure-contexts-only) requires https for geolocation usage

---

#### Troubleshooting  && Permissions Check / Debug Log

Check, user's **OPERATING SYSTEM and BROWSER** `BOTH` have location services enabled,  user's **browser** supports checking for location services

```
    // options for current position
    const navigatorLocationOptions = {
      enableHighAccuracy: true,
      timeout: 7000,
      maximumAge: 0
    };
 
    // does browser have geo services enabled
    navigator.permissions.query({name:'geolocation'})
      .then((result) => {
        
        if (result.state === 'granted') {// you are good
          navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(position => {
             console.log('granted user location permission', position );
              
             //.. do your stuff

          }, (error) => {
            // OS services are not enabled
            console.log('Please turn on OS located services', navigator);
            errorLocation();
          }, navigatorLocationOptions);

        } else {
          // browser issues seriveces
          console.log('Browser location services disabled', navigator);
          errorLocation();
        }
      }, (error) => {
        /* Browser doesn't support querying for permissions */
        console.log('Please turn on BROWSER location services', navigator);
        errorLocation()
      }
    );


    //handle errors
    function errorLocation() {
      ...
    }
```